# Transaction payment system for Australian website?

Tags: online-payment

I need to integrate a payment system into a website and I'm not sure which way to go. The website will be selling electronic services including

- Micro transactions
- Monthly Advertising
- Monthly subscriptions.

There will be payments of varying amounts, possibly ranging from $4 to $200. It would also be nice to automate the issuing of invoices for the monthly subscription. The payments would need to be instant and have callbacks to the site so it knows the current status of payment. The advertising is not so important for this. But the micro transactions and monthly member fees will be.

What is the best solutions? Will PayPal cover these needs is it optimal? I see there is a micro transaction account via Paypal but I do not see it offered in Australia. In any case the site will not just be making micro transactions but transactions of various amounts.

I saw somewhere about Visa Payclick but I could not find any information. Their website looks like it is dead.

Currently the shopping cart and the transaction system have not been developed. Still debating whether to build the shopping cart of find something lightweight to integrate. It is a complicated system.